# How connect tot Google Cloud SQL via Exposed

Tags: google-cloud-sql, ktor, kotlin-exposed

I develop app on GAE using Kotlin, Ktor. Database is CloudSQL. For connect to it use Exposed library

```
Database.connect(
            "jdbc:postgresql://cloudsql/<project-id>:<zone-name>:<instance-name>",
            driver="org.postgresql.Driver",
            user="postgres",
            password="********"
        )
```

But I get error:

> org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl log: IOException occurred while connecting to cloudsql:5432 (ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:317)
>   java.net.UnknownHostException: cloudsql
>
> .......

I try change url on:

```
    jdbc:postgresql://google/<project-id>:<zone-name>:<instance-name>
    jdbc:postgresql://cloudsql/<project-id>:<zone-name>:<instance-name>/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

But also can this error.

Error is geted both on local and server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolve my issue.
Url should be like:

```
jdbc:postgresql://<public_ip>/postgres
```